# AJAXContorlToolKit ModalExtender on web form

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit, modalpopup

I'm using C#/ASP.NET to make a project planning web app.  I'd to be able to click a day in the calendar and produce the data in the modal window.  This is due tomorrow and I could really use some assistance.  I have the ajaxcontroltoolkit installed.

This is what the old version looks like, which I totally had the ui right but wasn't able to pull in the data.
[image]

Thanks in advance.  I'm desperate at this point and in a hurry.

C# Code - pastebin.com/s2Zvgbtc

ASP Code - pastebin.com/mjpYRp6e

Comment: put your aspx and .cs what for filling modal pop ups

Comment: it wont fit @Ganesh_Devlekar

Comment: C# Code -  http://pastebin.com/s2Zvgbtc

Comment: ASP Code - http://pastebin.com/mjpYRp6e

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed. I did research and found it.